# Adding a default class to a group of links

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to add a default class to a bunch of links. So instead of

```
<a href=1 class=text1>1</a>
<a href=2 class=text1>2</a>
<a href=3 class=text1>3</a>
<a href=4 class=text1>4</a>
<a href=5 class=text1>5</a>
<a href=6 class=text1>6</a>
<a href=7 class=text1>7</a>
```

I want to do

```
<span class=text1>
<a href=1 >2</a>
<a href=2 >3</a>
<a href=3 >4</a>
<a href=4 >5</a>
<a href=5 >6</a>
<a href=6 >7</a>
<a href=7 >8</a>
</span>
```

where the text1 class is something like:

```
a.text1:link { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
a.text1:active { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
a.text1:visited { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
a.text1:hover { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;  }
```

However the second option doesn't seem to work. Am i being stupid or is there any way to make a bunch of links in a group like this follow a class?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
span.text1 a:link { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:active { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:visited { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:hover { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
span.text1 a:link {
    /* css */
}
```

Or, if necessary, select only the first-level descendants, the 'immediate' children:

```
span.text1 > a:link {
    /* css */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way.
Try this

```
span.text1 a:link { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:active { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:visited { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;}
span.text1 a:hover { color: white; text-decoration: underline ;  }
```